# Recursive StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, stack, stack-overflow

My goal is to make a small program that takes Scanner input and uses a STACK and RECURSION to reverse words.

Please note I know how to make a program that can do this. I am just having trouble making one work with both STACK and RECURSION.

For example input of "black is cat The" will output "The cat is black"

What I have causes a StackOverflowError where the commented line says.

Any Ideas on how to fix this or do this better would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Reverse
{

    public static String wordReverse(String[] theWords) {


       Stack <String> stacker = new Stack <String>();

       for(String wordsHold : theWords) {
            stacker.push(wordsHold);
        } 

        while ( !stacker.empty() ){
               stacker.pop();
        }       

        return wordReverse(theWords);  // Cause of StackOverflowError
        } 

    public static void main(String args[])

    {

        Scanner takeIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        String allWords = takeIn.nextLine();

        String[] goodWords = allWords.split(" ");

        System.out.println(wordReverse(goodWords)); 

        takeIn.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually, you use either an (explicit) stack, OR recursion - you appear to be attempting to use both.

Comment: Totally agree with @Blorgbeard, recursion is a stack itself.

Comment: Why don't you ever return a `String` in your method? It never ends.

Comment: Exacly like Blorgbeard said. Note that when you call your function recursively the variables are pushed to the stack anyway. Using your own stack rather than the CPU's stack is just an alternative, using it you do not use recursion, usually.

Comment: All you need to do is take the output of `stacker.pop()` and append it to a string, then return that string, instead of calling yourself. You won't be using recursion, but your function will work :)

Comment: If there's no place where the method returns without first calling itself then it's inevitable that stack overflow will occur.  How can the code ever "escape"?

Answer (score 1):

Since `wordReverse()` always calls `wordReverse(theWords)`, the recursion never ends. This will cause the program stack to overflow. It has nothing to do with the `stacker` variable though. It is just coincidental that your infinitely recursing method happens to be working with the `Stack<>` class.

You can consider implementing your `wordReverse()` like this

```
public static String wordReverse(String[] theWords) {

    Stack<String> stacker = new Stack<String>();

    for (String wordsHold : theWords) {
        stacker.push(wordsHold);
    }

    String ret = "";
    while (!stacker.empty()) {
        ret = ret + stacker.pop();
    }

    return ret;
}
```